# Exception when trying to access webservice through axis2 in java

Tags: java, apache-axis

I am trying to generate web service client through axis2, but I am getting this error:

> org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: No service named Port is available

Could you please help me out, when this error comes, why and how to resolve that.

Comment: You'll have to post the relevant part of your code/configuration. Otherwise no one will be able to help you.

Comment: Your title says that the exception happens when trying to access a web service. Your post says that the exception happens when generating a web service client. Please take more care when writing your questions.

Answer (score 0):

The question title and the actual question is different.
Could you please post how you are trying to generate the client through ant script or wsdl2java command, if so please paste ant content or command.

**wdl2java Ex:-**

%AXIS2_HOME%\bin\WSDL2Java -uri wsdlURL -p net.fmb.integrator.serviceprovider.unistream -d xmlbeans -s

**AntScript:-**

```
    <target name="cleanWsdl2JavaOutDir" description="cleanWsdl2JavaOutDir">
        <echo message=".......Cleaning the Previous SRC directory........"/>
        <delete dir="${outputdir}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${outputdir}"/>
     </target>

 <echo message=".............Processing wsdl2java................."/>   
 <target name="wsdl2java" depends="cleanWsdl2JavaOutDir">
    <delete dir="output" />
    <java classname="org.apache.axis2.wsdl.WSDL2Java" fork="true">
        <classpath refid="axis.classpath"/>
        <arg value="-d"/>
        <arg value="xmlbeans"/>
        <arg value="-uri"/>
        <arg value="${wsdlFile}"/>
        <arg value="-ss"/>
        <arg value="-g"/>
        <arg value="-sd"/>
        <arg value="-o"/>
        <arg file="${outputdir}"/>
        <arg value="-p"/>
        <arg value="${outputpkg}"/>
    </java> 
 </target>
```